# wordpress table is crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, phpmyadmin

I run a wordprees website and use a managed VPS server with cPanel/WHM. Got bellow error log and check the table. I repaired the table with repair table command from phpmyadmin. But this problem occur repeatedly.

```
131121 21:58:16 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './HIDDEN_wrdp2/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
HIDDDEN_wrdp2.wp_options info : Found block that points outside data file at 7534168
info : Found block that points outside data file at 7534212
warning : Duplicate key for record at 1150328 against record at 520756
warning : Number of rows changed from 25466 to 25463
status : OK
```

And I frequently find a screen showing error establishing database connection.

What should I do now? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have network connectivity issues.

Assuming the SAN of your VPS is connected using the same network (very likely), the database server could lose connection to its drives intermittently. That can cause all kinds of consistency issues within the databases.

As this is a hosted environment, you cannot diagnose or fix network issues yourself. Talk to your hosting provider and have them look at it.